# Move another ViewController from different storyboard in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In objective-C, to move another viewcontroller from different storyboard, we will use following coding to fulfil what we want.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Customer" bundle:nil];
HomeSummaryViewController *creaccVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeSummaryViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:creaccVC animated:YES];
```

In swift version, please help me to how to do just like Objective-C?

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty much identical to the Objective-C version.

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Customer", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeSummaryViewController")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: '_??' is not convertible to 'Void'

Comment: The code worked fine for me. Are you using Xcode 7 and Swift 2? Or perhaps there is an error somewhere else in your code.

Comment: The code i posted is written in Swift 2. You should consider upgrading to Xcode 7 and converting your project to Swift 2.

Answer (score 0):

The above code in Swift looks like this:

```
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Customer", bundle: nil)
    let homeView: HomeSummaryViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeSummaryViewController") as! HomeSummaryViewController 
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeView, animated: true)
```

Comment: 'AnyObject!' is not convertible to 'HomeSummaryViewController'

Comment: just add "as! HomeSummaryViewController" to the end of the second line. I also edited my answer

Comment: Not handling Optionals is a bad idea.